# XFCE4 settings is not permanent and is set to defaults on reboot

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, settings

I have **raspios**(**bullseye**) installed inside of my **Raspberry Pi 4 B** (**8GB**) with **XFCE4** Desktop environment...
When I restart my Pi, somehow my XFCE4 settings including panel and appearance, and everything gets reset to default...

I tried searching far and wide for this problem but didn't find any working solution for this problem...
Please is there any way to figure this problem out??? (i need to force my DE settings to be permanent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some tries, I found that **Thunar** and **xfce4** and **xfce4-dict** folders in `/home/{USER}/.config` are owned by **root** with permissions **700**(drwx------) which seems to be the problem...